# Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable

Tags: java, windows-subsystem-for-linux, xming

I am going through the tutorial found [here](https://github.com/nasa/trick) to build a test simulation. I am using WSL so therefore I am using XMing for my GUI. When I run `trick-dre` I get this error:
`Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using '0.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.` My desired result is upon running `trick-dre &` that the GUI opens. [This](https://nasa.github.io/trick/tutorial/ATutRecordingData) is the page of the tutorial I am currently on.

**Solutions I have tried:**

1. `sudo trick-dre &` does not give me the error but no GUI appears.
2. `unset DISPLAY` gives me error `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` upon executing `trick-dre`
3. I ran Xming with the -ac option: `Xming -ac`, This opens up a physical window of Xming but it is blank, not then GUI expected.
4. I ensured that my windows firewall is allowing Xming. It is.
5. Restarting WSL & restarting Xming.
6. Setting `DISPLAY` to my ip address rather than `0:0` or '0.0' this gives me `Exception in thread "main" java.awt.AWTError: Can't connect to X11 window server using <ipaddress>:0 as the value of the DISPLAY variable.`
7. I tried `xhost +` but it gives me
   `xhost:  unable to open display "0.0"`
8. Setting the `DISPLAY` to `localhost:0` produces the same error as solution 6.
9. I also ensured that Xming is running.
10. I am not using a remote host, only a local environment so it is my belief that ssh forwarding is not needed.

Note: Obviously I cannot enter headless mode because I need the GUI. These solutions are the culmination of a dozen or so relevant solutions to similar problems I found on other threads.

Answer (score 0):

your solution 6 description implies you use the command "export DISPLAY=0:0"?

Have you tried "export DISPLAY=:0.0" instead? I think :0.0 is the standard way to enable UI display.

If you need to su to other user, make sure you execute "xhost +" as the login user before you su.

Comment: Yes I have tried 0.0 as well. Same error message.  `xhost +` just gives me `xhost:  unable to open display "0.0"` so I can't do it before su

Comment: sorry, if i sound like i am repeating myself. But are you sure you type the correct command "export DISPLAY=:0.0" with a semicolon, a zero, a full stop, then a zero.
I asked because if i enter the command "export DISPLAY=0.0" without semicolon, and then execute "xhost +", i can replicate your error message, so i can only assume you missed the semicolon.